# splitting apart two objects that got stuck together

Tags: mesh

I took a block shaped it into  something, then took a circle then shaped it into something using excruding, deleting faces then moved them together. now they are stuck together.

how to I split it into the two objects it started out as?

[New Blend File]

[image]

Comment: Posting your blend file would help http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: oh more things to figure out... hold on... :D nope-- got  tell me how I do this posting files to a post in here.. PLS @Dontwalk

Comment: @uxserx-bw, to upload a .blend, upload it to [Blend- Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), and edit the resulting link into your question.

Comment: @Timaroberts Thanks, I book marked that sight too btw, Thanks!

Comment: @uxserx-bw Please do not put solved in the question title (you should be able to roll back that edit).  Instead, please up vote answers that were useful, and mark the one that answered your question as the answer.  The site will then mark it with the proper colors for others to easily tell it is answered.

Comment: @Gliderman it doesn't pay to try sometimes, everyone got their own set of rules in every fourm something different always. its worse then travling into different countires with different customs always something....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To separate your objects, go into *edit mode* on the problem object. I assume we are talking about "cube", and select all with <kbd>A</kbd>, then press <kbd>P</kbd>*>loose parts*.

Now you have two objects.

Comment: Nope still stuck together... I moved the stuck together away from the rest .. it is the circle and body that is stuck together now.. then added that to my orginal post to get the right idea

Comment: Interesting, worked for me on your model.

Comment: NEVERMIND -- I had to fanaggle it aorund a bit - But I got it now. thanks. First timer here .. still learning :D